# How do I exit a continuous while loop by some user input?

Tags: java, io

I'm pretty new to Java. I'm currently reading input from a URL which provides me with a real-time stream of text. I want to continually write this to a text file, so every time the URL gives a new string I add this to a string buffer, outside of my infinite while loop I write the contents of the buffer to my file. The trouble is, I need a way of exiting the while loop because the server never stops giving me data, so I want to do something such as enter 0 in the console to exit the while loop and write the contents to a file. On that subject, does anybody know if my object of the StringBuffer class will reach a storage limit?

Comment: Well I tried writing the response to a text file inside the while loop, but I can't successfully do this without closing the writer, so I have moved that command to outside of the while loop. I've tried editing the while condition to read input and break when a certain input is given, but this requires me to continually enter an input in order to test the condition. I just want to leave the stream running without having to press anything, then break by providing an input. Any particular check I can do?

Comment: See JB Nizet's answer. It's about as simple as you are likely to find. The multi-threading will be minimal. Something like: Thread background = new Thead() { doStuff(); }; background.start(); System.in.readLine(); background.interrupt();

Answer (score 2):

The loop should not write to an in-memory buffer, but to the file writer directly (wrapped inside a BufferedWriter). This will avoid running out of memory.

You should start a new thread which executes your while loop, and tests at each iteration if the thread has been asked to interrupt itself, using `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`. Once interrupted, the thread should stop the while loop, and close the writer.

Have your main thread read from the command line, and when the stop command is entered, call `interrupt()` on the writer thread.

Comment: Thanks. I introduced a StringBuffer because when writing to a text file line-by-line as the server gives me a new string just erases the previous string. Could you elaborate on using a BufferedWriter if that is a better solution? Also, is there any way to do this without using multi-threading? (I'm still a novice) What I'm doing at the moment is:

do {
    response = connectionInputReader.readLine();
    if (response != null) {
       buffer.append(response);
    }
} while (true);

// Write contents and close writer.

I thought maybe there's a while condition that checks for user intervention?

Comment: @JB Nizet: Hmm, indeed. That is a nice way of working. I'll remember that. +1

Answer (score 0):

When you bring "Infinity" into picture, YES things are going to run out of memory at some point.

To exit a loop, you can have it running in a separate thread and let the main thread listen to the user inputs. And based on the input, the main thread will alter a shared variable, usually a boolean to determine an end.

Comment: Bringing in multiple threads for (what seems like) a relatively trivial loop seems overly complex, especially for somebody who started their question by saying they're pretty new to Java.

Comment: @Reece : I have updated the answer, but your comments are a bit rude. Try to tone it down. Thanks

Comment: @Reece: do your own research and write your own code. There is no need to be rude.

Comment: @Reece Insulting people isn't the best way to encourage them (or others) to help you out by answering your questions. There isn't a hard limit, it's all dependent on the memory Java has available to use and how much of it it's using for everything aside from your StringBuffer instance.

Comment: I read "When you bring "Infinity" into picture, YES things are going to run out of memory at some point." and didn't see the below, so I thought you were just being deliberately unhelpful. My bad, apologies. Is there any way to do this without multi-threading?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `break;` statmement, you can break out of the most inner loop. I would suggest to create a boolean field called `running`. Each iteration of the loop, check it. If false, quit the loop.

Or even more efficient would be using the boolean as while-condition:

```
/* Declaration */
public volatile boolean running = true;

/* Code */
running = true;
while (running)
{


}
```

Based on user-input, put the running flag on false.

You could try something like this to make the flag turn to false when you type something in the console:

```
new Thread("User Input Handler", new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            System.in.read();
            running = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Why not use the standard interruption mechanism? See my anser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `break;` statement to jump out of the loop. What you'll need to do is check the input that you've read in against whatever you want your stopping condition to be, and if they match up then call `break;`. Something like this:

```
while(true) {
    String input = /* read input */;
    if("0".equals(input)
        break;
    /* whatever you want to do if you haven't hit your stopping condition */
}
```

Comment: Many people (myself included) avoid breaks due to it breaking "structured" code concepts. The whole "one entrance, one exit" thing.